# How to change the value of a torch tensor with requires_grad=True so that the backpropogation can start again?

Tags: python, pytorch

```
a=torch.tensor([1,2],dtype=dtype,requires_grad=True)
b=a[0]*a[1]
b.backward()
print(a.grad)
```

but when I use `a+=1` and want to give `a` another value and do another round of backpropogation, it shows that a leaf Variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation.

However `a=a+1` seems right. What's the difference between a=a+1 and a+=1?
(solved)

I find my doubt about torch actually lies in the following small example,

```
a=torch.tensor([1,2],dtype=dtype,requires_grad=True)
b=a[0]*a[1]
b.backward()
print(a.grad)

print(a.requires_grad)
c=2*a[0]*a[1]
c.backward()
print(a.grad)
```

When I do the first round of backpropogation, I get a.grad=[2,1].
Then I want to make a fresh start and calculate the differential of c with respect to a, however, the gradient seems to accumulate. How can I eliminate this effect?

Comment: It seems a.grad=None works, but I want to know the exact how the gradient accumulates

Comment: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-do-we-need-to-set-the-gradients-manually-to-zero-in-pytorch/4903

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+=` operator is for in-place operations, while `a = a+1` is not in-place (that is, `a` refers to a *different* tensor after this operation).

But in your example you don't seem to be using either of these, so it is hard to say what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the difference now, and I find my doubt about torch actually lies in another example, I am editing my question now